# How to set Background in Scala swing

Tags: swing, scala

I'm looking at example 6.9 in Steps in Scala, and his method for setting the background is inadequate as when the frame is resized, the background does not change. The example code (updated for changes to work on version 2.10 is:

```
import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._

object circle extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    var mouseX = 0
    var mouseY = 0
    var mouseclicked = false
    title = "Draw Circle"
    val rect = new java.awt.Rectangle(350,250)
    preferredSize = new Dimension(350,250)
    val canvas = new Panel {
      border = Swing.EmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15)
      opaque = false
      override def paintComponent(g: java.awt.Graphics2D) {
     // g.setBackground(java.awt.Color.magenta)
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.magenta)
        g.fill(rect)
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.blue)
          if ( mouseclicked ) {
            g.fillOval(mouseX-10, mouseY-10, 20, 20)
            mouseclicked = false
          }
      }
      listenTo(mouse.clicks)
      reactions += {
        case MouseClicked(_, p, _, 1, _) => {  
          mouseX = p.x
          mouseY = p.y
          mouseclicked = true 
          repaint
        }
      }
    }
    contents = canvas
  }
}
```

I tried replacing the g.setColor(...) and g.fill(rect) with g.setBackground(...) as commented out in the above, and it compiles but does not work.

Can someone suggest the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to let Swing do the background painting

```
val canvas = new Panel {
  opaque = true
  background = Color.magenta
  override def paintComponent(g: java.awt.Graphics2D) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue)
    if (mouseclicked) {
      g.fillOval(mouseX - 10, mouseY - 10, 20, 20)
      mouseclicked = false
    }
  }
```